# update id column with random values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not very strong in SQL, so could you help please?

I have a table with 100 rows
I need to change their ids for random values

now it's 1, 2,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7
I want 28, 30, 19, 1, 84 etc.

how can I do it?

p.s. this database is used for photogallery, and order of photos depends on their ids. 
I want to change id so order become different.

Comment: Are you looking for just any random values?  Can ids be repeated?  Are you trying to shuffle the values that are there?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to change the automatically generated IDs for something random.  You could generate the ID yourself, but you'd need to check to make sure it hadn't already been used.

A simpler option would be not to sort by the photo id - you can try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
ORDER BY RAND()
```

This will also make the photos appear in a different order each time (I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Well, it didn't work because photos are displayed by their id. But I founded another tricky solution — I created another column "id-2", generated random numbers, deleted "id" and renamed "id-2" to "id"

it's not bad? or it is?

Comment: RAND() will generate duplicate numbers at some point - they are not unique.  So you can't use them for an id value - eventually you'll get two photos with the same random ID.  You'll need to put your query and table structure in your question if you need further help, as it's hard to guess what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be changing their IDs.  If you want them to show up randomly, you should just use RAND() in the ORDER BY clause.

Here is a SQL Fiddle Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be776/1